# How to replace multiple value in columns?

Tags: python

I imported a csv file, there is a column called 'Designation' inside the csv. It has multi value, 79 to be exact. I wanted to replace some of the values to "0" and only keep the values that I want. How can I do it? Here's my script:

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('test.csv', index_col=0)
df2['designation'].unique()
```

and the return value is :

```
array(['Designation Chairman of Nomination Committee',
           'Previous Position Chairman of Nomination Committee',
           'Designation Member of Nomination Committee',
           'Previous Position Member of Nomination Committee',
           'Designation Director', 'Designation Non-Executive Director',
           'Description Cease to be a member of Nomination Committee',
           'Description Relinquishment', 'Description Relinquished',
           'Description Relinquish position as a member of the Nomination Committee',
           'Description According to Resolution 6 of Eighteenth (18th) Annual General Meeting of Scomi Group Berhad (SGB) Mr. Lionel Leo was not re-elected.',
           'Description Review of membership composition of the Board Nomination and Remuneration Committee',
           'Designation Others',
           'Description Step Down as Chairman and member of Nomination Committee',
           'Designation Chairman',
           'Description Ceased to be a member following the reconstitution of the Nominating Committee.',
           'Description Stepped down as a Member of the Nomination Committee',
           'Description Appointment as member of the Nomination and Remuneration Committee',
           'Description Appointment as chairman of the Nomination and Remuneration Committee',
           'Description Relinquish',
           'Previous Position Non-Executive Director',
           'Designation Executive Director',
           'Description Stepped down as a member of the Board Nomination and Remuneration Committee',
           'Description Ceased as Member',
           'Description Re-composition of STMKB Board Committees effective 14 August 2020',
           'Designation Deputy Chairman',
           'Description Re-designation from Non-Independent Non-Executive Director to Independent Non-Executive Director',
           'Description Cessation as Chairman arising from redesignation to executive role',
           'Description Change to other Committee',
           'Description Re-designation of Directorate from Independent and Non-Executive Director to Non-Independent and Non-Executive Director.',
           'Description Review of membership composition in view of his appointment as Chairman Non-Independent Non-Executive Director of TNB',
           'Description Relinquished membership', 'Previous Position Others',
           'Description Appointment as member of Nomination Committee',
           'Description Resignation as member of Nomination Committee',
           'Description Appointment as Member of the Nomination and Remuneration Committee',
           'Description Appointment as Chairman of the Nomination and Remuneration Committee',
           'Description Expiry of the term of appointment as member of the Nomination and Remuneration Committee',
           'Description Election of Nomination Committee Chairman',
           'Description Relinquish the post of Chairman of Nomination Committee and remain as a member of the Nomination Committee.',
           'Description Resignation and Re-designation of Nominating and Remuneration Committee members of Ranhill Holdings Berhad',
           'Description Appointment as Chairman of the Nomination and Remuneration Committee ("NRC")',
           'Description Appointment as Member of the Nomination and Remuneration Committee ("NRC")',
           'Description "Due to re-designated of Dato Hussian @ Rizal Bin A. Rahman as Managing Director"',
           'Description Stepped down as a member arising from the reconstitution of the Group Nomination & Remuneration Committee by the Board',
           'Description Stepped down as member of the Nomination Committee',
           'Description Relinquish the post as Chairman of Nomination Committee and remain as a member of the Nomination Committee',
           'Description Vacation of office as Nomination Commiittee Member pursuant to his redesignation as Executive Director',
           'Previous Position Chairman',
           'Description Ceased to be a member of Nomination Committee',
           'Description Ceased as member following restructuring of committee',
           'Designation Chairman & Executive Director',
           'Designation Managing Director',
           'Description Encik Razalee bin Amin ceased to be a member of the Board Nomination Committee following the change in the composition and the formation of the merged Board Nomination and Remuneration Committee.',
           'Previous Position Director',
           'Description Redesignation of Mr. Luigi Fortunato Ghirardello from Independent Non-Executive Director to Non-Independent Non-Executive Director effective from 29 July 2017.',
           'Description Change of Nomination Committee member',
           'Description "Change of status of Tunku Dato Mahmood Fawzy bin Tunku Muhiyiddin to Independent Non-Executive Member."',
           'Designation Chairman & Director',
           'Designation Chief Operating Officer',
           'Designation Director & Chief Exec. Officer',
           'Designation Vice Chairman',
           'Description Appointment as member of the Nomination and Remuneration Committee ("N&RC")',
           'Description Appointment as Chairman of the Nomination and Remuneration Committee ("N&RC")',
           'Description Please refer to remarks below.',
           'Description Removed by shareholders by virtue of Extraordinary General Meeting held on 29 September 2016.',
           'Description Change in Directorate',
           'Description Due to his not sought for his re-appointment as Director of the Company during the 32nd Annual General Meeting of the Company held 23 May 2016.',
           'Description "Dato Ng ceases to be a member of the Nomination Committee due to reconstitution of the Board Committees subsequent to the changes in the composition of the Board."',
           'Description Change of Chairman of the Nomination Committee',
           'Description Relinquishment of Membership',
           'Description Appointment and Re-designation',
           'Description Ceased to be a member following the restructuring of the Board Committees',
           'Description Relinquishment of membership'], dtype=object)
```

I want to replace some of the values with 0, only 'Previous Position Chairman of Nomination Committee' and 'Previous Position Director'.

Comment: So do you want those 2 values to be replaced with zeros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple snippet should do that:

```
to_replace = ["Previous Position Chairman of Nomination Committee",
              "Previous Position Director"]

df.loc[df["designation"].isin(to_replace),
   "designation"] = 0
```

It checks whether each row in the column designation can be found in the list to_replace, then it replaces it with 0.

Comment: it return this error ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: @YazidYaakub could you share the csv / excel / txt file with the data?

Comment: yea sure @A.M. Ducu, here you go https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gctnP6bifTesf6unjfZTDnVIwycJUr8w/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @YazidYaakub it should work as intended now.

Comment: I think you can go even simpler than that: `df[df.designation.isin(to_replace)] = 0`, or am I missing something?

Comment: @fsimonjetz if you don't specify the column name, all elements of the row change to 0

Comment: @A.M.Ducu I see, so indeed I *did* miss something (I was testing with a test df with only one column so it appeared to work)... Thank you very much!

Comment: @fsimonjetz no worries. Glad it was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
df['designation'] = df['designation'].replace(['Previous Position Chairman of Nomination Committee', 'Previous Position Director'], [0, 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use replace function in pandas module.

```
df['column name'] = df['column name'].replace(['1st old value','2nd old value',...],'new value')
```

Replace multiple values with a new value for an individual DataFrame column.

```
df['designation'] = df['designation'].replace(['Previous Position Chairman of Nomination Committee','Previous Position Director'],0)
```